# How to check if wpa_supplicant.conf has any syntax errors?

Tags: freebsd, configuration, wpa-supplicant

I would like to know if there is a tool that allows me to check if I made any syntax errors in [wpa_supplicant.conf(5)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?wpa_supplicant.conf).

I am looking for a utility for [wpa_supplicant(8)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?wpa_supplicant) that would server the same purpose as the `--check` flag of [visudo(8)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?visudo) from the  [sudo(8)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?sudo) suite.

The only solution I've come up with so far is running

```
wpa_supplicant -c wpa_supplicant.conf -iNonexistentInterface`
```

but it is less than ideal. Partially because the return code is always 255 due to the invalid interface name.

Ideally, I'd like the utility to run on FreeBSD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand your wish but know of no such thing. It would be a nice feature. But I think you are close already now.

There is however another utility named [wpa_cli](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?wpa_cli) which might be helpful if you are willing to consider a slightly different approach. Or maybe you know it and have already discarded the idea.

It is available along with [wpa_supplicant.conf](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=wpa_supplicant) in the base system:

```
$ uname -r
11.1-RELEASE
$ wpa_cli -v
wpa_cli v2.5
Copyright (c) 2004-2015, Jouni Malinen <j@w1.fi> and contributors
```

[Version 2.7](https://www.freshports.org/security/wpa_supplicant/) is available as a port.

The man page is unfortunately not kept quite up-to-date. Neither is the [readme](https://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/plain/wpa_supplicant/README)

`wpa_cli -help` lists all current options. And of those these might be interesting:

- reconfigure
- set
- dump
- save_config

If you can live with the fact that you are changing the live settings - then `set` allows you to adapt the config and get errors for each setting. When things are to your liking you can then use `save_config`.

Another - probably obvious - idea would be to add `-dd` to your `wpa_supplicant` command line. But still not ideal.

But your general idea is actually workable. Though it seems that it always flakes out with exit code 255 no matter what the error. The textual output is easy to parse.

If you have a parse failure you can always look for:

```
Failed to read or parse configuration '{}'.
```

All parse failures are prepended with `Line {}:`

But a suggestion upstream to allow for `-t` for test in place of `-i` and more granular exit status might be a good idea.